# Get item row in db table as object based on Id of item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table called Modules based on Domain Model Module.
If i want to add new Module i can do this

```
 _db.Modules.Add(module);//module is object of type Module
    _db.SaveChanges();
```

now if i want to delete I could do

```
_db.Modules.Remove(module);
```

but in my delete method below how can I achieve this, if I only pass the Id?
I tried to do following, but it doesn't work. No changes, row still exists.

```
 _db.Modules.Remove(_db.Modules.Find(module.Id));
```

here is the Delete method

```
public ActionResult DeleteModule(long id)
        {

            var module = new Module {Id = id};
            _db.Modules.Remove(_db.Modules.Find(module.Id));
            _db.SaveChanges();

            //_db.Modules.Remove(module);
            Information("Your widget was deleted");
            return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new { area = "Hardware" });
        }
```

How can I delete the row? Based upon the Id value that is passed as parameter of method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var module = new Module() { Id = id };
_db.Entry(module).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: worked like a charm. You saved my day again. And for interesting note, my previous code worked as well but it only shows changes after some time, but with your code changes are seen instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Module and delete it instead of creating a new Module object.

```
public ActionResult DeleteModule(long id)
{ 
   var module = _db.Modules.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
   _db.Modules.Remove(module);
   _db.SaveChanges();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Is there any way to add some kind of confirmation message dialog box, before item is deleted. Like a dialog box with are you sure you want to delete? and on pressing Yes item gets deleted. I tried to look up but didn't find something useful

Comment: The confirmation message should be displayed at client side using Javascript. Once you reach to action method, it is too late.